# react native 0.60 add react-native-fbsdk module

Tags: react-native

I am using the latest version of react native 0.60
When I add the react-native-fbsdk module
The document does not seem to apply

Does anyone know how to add the react-native-fbsdk module in react native 0.60?

Platform: Android

Comment: Are you saying that you followed the installation guide but not the installation?

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to do, really. You simply need to skip the `Link` section of the instructions, as stated in the [installation guide](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/README.md) and then configure both projects with your Facebook App Id.